# How do I bind ng-click inside a filter function

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

In my partial I have the following html

```
<div class="content"  bo-html="myText | mention"></div>
```

which scans the text and replaces twitter @handle names with  a link as follows,

```
 text = text.replace(/\B@([\w-]+)/gm, '<a  ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-click="openProfile()"  class=""> @$1</a>');
```

Now the replace works fine but when I click the link nothing happens I tried logging inside the openProfile() function in my myCtrl but nothing happens

Any ideas?

Comment: You always enter the controller again? The controller has to be the shell around your elements like ngClick.

Comment: Well I tried wrapping it around with a span tag and adding the ng-controller to it but the click still won't bind

Comment: Did you `compile` the new generated `text`?

Comment: No, How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to inject in your filter `$compile` service, and when your text is ready you need to `$compile` it

`text = $compile(text)`

[check more about compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: ok, bring your code in in jsfiddle I will update on you code ok ?